# Have Unattended-Upgrade perform check before restarting

Tags: apt, unattended-upgrades

Unattended-Upgrade upgrades and restarts my machine without any issues. However, I have a python script that runs infrequently, but when it runs it may take days to complete. I would like to suspend automatic reboots while this script runs.

What is the easiest way of achieving this?

Comment: Unattended upgrades does not allow a way to run a command to check. It, instead, uses the presence of `/var/run/reboot-required` to restart - so, if you could somehow prevent that file from being formed while your process is running...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to create a script that checks if python is running and creates and deletes a configuration override file accordingly. Of course the test for the running python program can be more spicific, for example using `-f /proc/$(cat something.pid)/status`.

The bash files is:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
case "$(pgrep -xc python)" in

0) echo "No python running, ok to reboot" >> /root/scripts/pythonCheck.log
   if [ -e "/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/60dontreboot" ]; then
     rm "/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/60dontreboot"
   fi
;;

*) echo "Python is running, shouldn't reboot" >> /root/scripts/pythonCheck.log
   if [ ! -e "/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/60dontreboot" ]; then
     echo 'Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "false"' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/60dontreboot
   fi
   ;;
esac
```

In my case, I have set the automatic reboot for 4am (also in 50unattended-upgrades), so I have added a crontab to execute the above script at 3:59am. I am happy with loosing one minute of work; my python script will just begin a couple of minutes later.

The crontab entry is:

```
59 3 * * * /root/scripts/pythonCheck.sh
```

Comment: I find it unlikely that the *only* python process that's running is your script, unless you don't have any GUI elements at all. Also, you don't have to replace that particular line. Just create a `60dontreboot` file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` that contains `Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "false";`, and delete it when done. Later files override earlier ones.

Comment: I have used a specific pid file in my actual code, but I wanted to keep the answer most general. When you say: "later files override earlier ones", do you mean by timestamp or because `60 > 50`?

Comment: Because 60 > 50 (in lexicographic ordering, 6 > 50 as well).

Comment: may I enquire the reason for the downvote?

Comment: At the moment, that comment only notifies me. And I didn't downvote.

Comment: That is true, but I didn't really know where else to ask. Anyway,  I got a response in the comments to the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the configuration in this file (thx @[muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru)):

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
```

and this line:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "false";
```

In a shell I would do that:

```
sudo sed -i 's/^Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";$/Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "false";/g' /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
```

Create a script for that and start you program inside the script. If it's finished revert the changes.

---

Or you can use this file:

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic
```

and this line:

```
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";
```

- "0" means disabled
- ">0" is the time interval in days.

This disables auto-update system-wide.

Comment: It would be better to disable automatic restart (`Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "false";`) than disable unattended upgrades altogether.

Comment: I don't want to disable automatic upgrade or automatic reboot, I just want to put either of them on hold while my python process is running.

Comment: @Karalga I have improved my answer.

Comment: hmm, but then the python process would need to run as root. But I suppose I could run a cron job that checks if my process is running, and if so change the line in `unattended-upgrades`. If its not running, the cron job could enable automatic restart again.

Comment: @Karalga: As you've never accepted any answer on this site: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: I have to admit, I don't think the answer is particuarly useful to anybody else, and it doesn't address the issue of checking if the python script is running at all.